# Halving each continuous number looping

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, encoding, python-idle

A cup is poured 1/2 full, then 1/4 full, then 1/8 full and so forth. Construct a loop that calculates how full the cup is after a given number of pours.

My question here is how to halve each number after the last

so far i have

```
cup=0
while cup<1:
    print(cup, "cup is full")
    cup+=1/2
```

I can only add 1/2 and make it tell me when the cup is full.

Comment: should it not be `cup = cup + cup * 1/2` instead ?

Comment: This algorithm question is barely a python question and definitely not an encoding or idle question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
amount_to_fill = .5
current_fill = 0
loops = 10
for i in range(loops):
    current_fill += amount_to_fill
    amount_to_fill /= 2
print "cup is {}% full".format(current_fill*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cup should *start* at 1. It should then be `cup *= 0.5` for each pour, since you are subtracting half the contents from a cup at each pour, by the sound of it (rather than filling up an empty cup).

Answer (score 0):

```
cup = 0
amountToFill = .5
count = 1

while cup < 1:
    print "#{} The cup is {} full".format(count, cup)
    cup += amountToFill
    amountToFill /= 2
    count += 1
```